# How do you compare values from AngularJS form data and MySQL database (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I can display the entire table of my database on my partial view, but what I want is to filter that and compare one of them with the output from my form. This is how I display my entire table.

**server/fetch.php**

```
<?php 

  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ralph2012", "mipadsignup");
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tbl_codes");

  $data = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  print json_encode($data);
?>
```

**app.js (where my controller is)**

```
http.get("server/fetch.php").success(function(response){
  scope.response = response;
}).error(function() {
  scope.response = "error in fetching data";
});
```

**registration.php**

```
<ul ng-repeat="codes in response">
  <li>{{codes.id}} {{codes.code}} {{codes.branch}} {{ formData.branches.alias }}</li>
</ul>
```

The `formData.branches.alias` is taken from the output produced by one of my form elements. I want its value to be compared to `codes.branch`, which is from the database. I do not want to list everything. I just want a portion of my `codes.branch` to run a check within its similar row values.

After comparing the two, I want to run again through its columns and check if any of them are available. If they are, I will randomly select one of the values to be inserted to my other table in the database.

[UPDATE]: As requested, this is my form

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.name.$invalid}" type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" required minlength="2" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.igname.$invalid}" type="text" name="igname" ng-model="formData.igname" minlength="2" placeholder="Instagram Name (Optional)">
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.email.$invalid}" ng-model="formData.email" ng-pattern="/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="mobile" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.mobile.$invalid}" ng-model="formData.mobile" required class="form-control" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Mobile Number">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <span class="nullable">
      <select id="regions" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.location" required ng-options="rg as rg.type for rg in region">
        <option value="">Choose Location</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="nullable">
      <select id="branches" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.branches" required ng-options="c as c[formData.location.displayName] for c in formData.location.data | orderBy:'branch'">
        <option value="">Choose Branch</option>
      </select>   
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <button type="submit" class="submit btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I run my checks here (registration.php):

```
<form id="signup-form" name="signup" ng-submit="processForm(signup.$valid)" novalidate>
  <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
  <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
</form>

<pre style="margin-top: 2em;">
  <h3 style="margin:0 0 0 12px; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">Form Validation Test</h3>
  <span>If it displays, it's valid.</span>
  {{ formData.name }}
  {{ formData.igname }}
  {{ formData.email }}
  {{ formData.mobile }}
  {{ formData.location.type }}
  {{ formData.branches.branch }}
  {{ formData.branches.alias }}
</pre>
```

I want to assign just one `codes.code` to the registered user and mark the `taken` column with `1` as the code can never be reused by other registered users, until it rans out and gives a message that no more codes are available for registration.

This is where I insert all the inputs to the other table in my database.

```
http.post("server/insert.php",{'code': $code, 'fullname': scope.formData.name, 'instagram': scope.formData.igname, 'email': scope.formData.email, 'mobile': scope.formData.mobile, 'location': scope.formData.location.type, 'branch': scope.formData.branches.branch}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      console.log("inserted successfully");
    });
```

and the **server/insert.php**

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$code = $request->code;
@$fullname = $request->fullname;
@$instagram = $request->instagram;
@$email = $request->email;
@$mobile = $request->mobile;
@$location = $request->location;
@$branch = $request->branch;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_registration (code,fullname,instagram,email,mobile,location,branch,date_registered) VALUES ('" . $code . "', '" . $fullname . "', '" . $instagram . "', '" . $email . "','" . $mobile . "','" . $location . "','" . $branch . "','" . $date . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check them against themselves and display them if they are equal see below code as per seeing your form. i'm wondering wouldn't this suffice your needs? add the code as an input in your form like below:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.name.$invalid}" type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" required minlength="2" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="codes in response | orderBy:random | limitTo:1" ng-if="codes.branch == formData.branches.alias && codes.taken == 0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" ng-model="formData.code" ng-value="codes.id">
  </ul>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.igname.$invalid}" type="text" name="igname" ng-model="formData.igname" minlength="2" placeholder="Instagram Name (Optional)">
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.email.$invalid}" ng-model="formData.email" ng-pattern="/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="mobile" ng-class="{'has-error': $submitted && signup.mobile.$invalid}" ng-model="formData.mobile" required class="form-control" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Mobile Number">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <span class="nullable">
      <select id="regions" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.location" required ng-options="rg as rg.type for rg in region">
        <option value="">Choose Location</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="nullable">
      <select id="branches" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.branches" required ng-options="c as c[formData.location.displayName] for c in formData.location.data | orderBy:'branch'">
        <option value="">Choose Branch</option>
      </select>   
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <button type="submit" class="submit btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript for random order :

```
$scope.random = function(){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
};
```

Comment: I managed to filter it like this: `<ul ng-repeat="codes in response">
  <li ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
    <strong>{{codes.id}}</strong> 
    {{codes.code}}
  </li>
</ul>` Now I want to extract one of those codes and use it to include in the form submit to assign to a new registered user. This is why I did not want to list them all.

Comment: Could you post more html of the form so i could come up with some logic behind your request?

Comment: Thanks, @SjoerdDeWit! We're almost closed to solving this. Apparently, placing {{ value }} on the value parameter in `input` gets an error at the console and thus not displaying anything. It outputs a typical error of 404 not found to favicon.ico or something. This usually happens when I do something weird with the displaying of {{ value }}. Do you think simply placing `value={{ value }}` is not the right way to do it?

Comment: Also, when `| limitTo` is used. When I switch the values using the dropdown menu, it no longer updates. It sticks to the first element. This is just [0] all the time and not running on all available values randomly.

Comment: value should've been ng-value as for the random order see the updated answer @ralphcarlo